# Combine a dataframe with coordinates and a dataframe with shapefiles to create a map with polygons and points

Tags: r, r-sp, rgdal

I have the following map boundaries in this .gdb [folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z8n44rgbdczue8h/AAAZQ8E0sySF15EDJhR4QhQMa?dl=0)

and here I have a  [csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvoeat6r6paj9nb/school_report_data_fake.csv?dl=0) which contains the variables that I want to plot and the coordinates of the points that need to be displayed on the map. My final goal is to create a map with polygons and inside every polygon there should be  points the student ids.

I use :

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)


# The input file geodatabase-change the filepath when you download the gdb folder
fgdb <- "C:/Users/makis/Documents/school/TPS_school_boundaries_2017.gdb"

fc <- readOGR(dsn=fgdb,layer="TPS_high_school_bdy" )


#Load the csv file and name it s
    s2<-data.frame(s)


# Assignment modified according
coordinates(s2) <-  c('lon', 'lat')


# Set the projection of the SpatialPointsDataFrame using the projection of the shapefile
proj4string(s2) <- proj4string(fc)

final<-over(fc,s2)
```

But I get a useless datframe full of NAs

Comment: The link to the .gdb file doesn't work. Any chance you can provide a small fake data set in the question body that we can copy and paste?

Comment: does the link to the csv works?

Comment: Does the link for the gdb works now?

Comment: Yeah, they both work now.

Comment: great to have a second opinion on this since itss the 1st time I work on gis data